# Empty array on $_POST when I send data with fetch

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I am trying to send data from JavaScript with `fetch` to PHP but in PHP I get empty array when I do `$_POST`.

```
async function updatesProf(data) {

    const dataUpdate = {
        method:"POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ data: data })
    };

    await fetch('synthese', dataUpdate)
    .then(response => response.json()).then(res => data )
    .catch(error => console.log("Error: "+error));

}
```

Comment: This isn't axios, this is fetch.  Also, what's in `data` when you post it?  In your browser's debugging tools, is any data included in the HTTP request?  Why in the response do you ignore the response and return the originally posted data?  Why return that at all when nothing uses it afterward?  Please clarify the specific debugging you've observed.

Comment: I have that as an answer in the debugbar
{
"data": [
5
]
},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic Problem, if you send your $_Post with Javascript.

Try with:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if(isset($_POST)){
    var_dump($_POST); 
}
```